# Photo Goo App to squeeze and twirl the camera input

Tags: photos

Is there a way to use the camera on Android like  with the old built-in [Photo Booth](http://www.apple.com/ipad-air/built-in-apps/#photobooth) app on iOS?

Photo Booth can apply effects on your photos like mirror, squeeze, twirl, kaleidoscope, light tunnel and stretch:

[image]